# smart-git does not refresh updated file automatically?

Tags: git

smart-git does not refresh updated file automatically, every time need to press F5. I am using Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS and smart-git 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

I have my home directory backed up using Git, but I have everything ignored by default (and only backup the files I specifically want).

However, if I understand it correctly, SmartGit interprets this as "oh, these directories are ignored, I won't scan any files in them," even if they happen to be tracked in other Git repos.

I appended this line to `~/.smartgit/7.1/smartgit.properties`, and it fixed my problem:

```
smartgit.filemonitor.excludeIgnoredDirectories=false
```

Comment: Correction: this fixed a small subset of my problem... :-/

Comment: If you need to make corrections to your answer, do not use the comments. Rather, update the answer itself. ;)

Comment: said properties are officially [documented here](http://www.syntevo.com/doc/display/SG/System+Properties)... but this is indeed not solvinig the problem. (I experience refresh issues with smartgit on a "on and off" basis...)